# Orthogonal projection and bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

Let $P: \mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ is orthogonal projection on $x\mathbb Oy$ plane:

a)Prove that is linear transformation

b)Find a matrix of $P$ using standard base.

c)Find matrix of that linear transformation using base $B=\{(1,0,1,),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)\}$

For a) I know, but for b) that is $P(e_1)=e_1$, $P(e_2)=e_2$, $P(e_3)=0$, so matrix P is

$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &0 &0\\
 0& 1& 0\\
 0& 0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$

and for c)

If I use formula $P=S^{-1}P´S,$

where

$S^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
 1& 1& 1\\
  0& 1& 1\\
  1& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$

$S=\begin{bmatrix}
 1& -1& 0\\
  1& 0& -1\\
  -1& 1& 1
\end{bmatrix}$

so $SPS^{-1}=P´$
¨ 
then 
$P´=\begin{bmatrix}
 1& 0& 0\\
  1& 1& 1\\
  -1& 0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$

is this ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all correct, indeed also for point "c" we have that

$$S^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
 1& 1& 1\\
  0& 1& 1\\
  1& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

represents the change of basis from the new basis to the standard one therefore we have

$$P'=SPS^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Almost OK, but it's rather with $S$ and $S^{-1}$ exchanged.
If $B$ denotes the matrix with the new basis as column vectors, $PB$ will produce their images under $P$, coordinated in the standard basis, and $B^{-1}$ of this will turn them to coordinates in the new basis.

Comment: It seems to me that $P'=SPS^{-1}$ is also correct.

Comment: @gimusi Do you mean the *formula* $P'=SPS^{-1}$ is correct, or that $SPS^{-1}$ happens to evaluate to the correct answer?

Comment: @Acccumulation I mean both of them! $S^{-1}$ has been defined properly and it doesn't matter if we indicate that as $S$ or as $S^{-1}$.

Comment: The OP seems to be using $S^{-1}=B$, and you seem to be saying the forumula is $B^{-1}PB$, so $SPS^{-1}$ works out to being equivalent to what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't seen the notation  $x\mathbb Oy$  before, but I guess I can figure it out from context.

For part (c), you can you change of basis, or you can just work it out from its action. Let $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$. Then $P(b_1)= (1,0,0)= b_1+b_2-b_3$. So $P(b_1)$, written in terms of the basis $B$, is $(1,1,-1)$. $P(b_2)=0b_1+b_2+0b_3 \rightarrow (0,1,0)$. $P(b_3)$ is also just $b_2$, or $(0,1,0)$. So to create the matrix representation of $P$, we just take those as columns vectors:

$P=\begin{bmatrix}
 1& 0& 0\\
  1& 1& 1\\
  -1& 0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Note that there's a difference between "the matrix of P" and "the matrix P". $P$ is not a matrix, it's a linear operator. In the standard basis, it's *represented* by the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &0 &0\\
 0& 1& 0\\
 0& 0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$

but as this question shows, $P$ is represented by a different matrix in a different basis, so we need to distinguish between the two.